# radio button and display widgets on designer-qt4

Tags: python, qt, pyside

I have a shell script with an old text-based user interface: I want to replace my shell code with python and create a graphical user interface using qt designer tool and pyside.

I was able to add a menu bar, a tab and some radio buttons.

When a user selects a radio button I would like to show in a text box a brief description of what that selection means; when it selects another radio button a different description on the same text box should appear and so on.

My questions are:

1. What widget should I use as text box ? I was thinking at Text
   Browser as Display Widget, but I'm not sure. A Label ? A Text Edit ?
2. When I connect a radio button to the Text Browser I can see some
   interesting slots under the Text Browser such as insertHtml or
   insertPlainText, but as soon as I select the signal clicked() on the
   radio button they disappear and I'm not even able to find them
   again.
3. I tried also to connect a button with a Label widget, but I'm
   not able to find any kind of setText slot. Reading the documentation
   I know setText exists, but I cannot use it inside my code.

Thanks for any kind of your support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qt has several different built-in APIs for showing help messages to the user, so I would suggest you give consideration to these before trying to roll your own solution:

- For simple a message that describes what the GUI element *is*, you can set a [tooltip](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#toolTip-prop).
- For slightly longer messages that describe what a GUI element *does*, you can set a [status tip](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#statusTip-prop). These are most often used for menu items and toolbar buttons.
- For longer, more informative messages, you can use [what's this mode](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwhatsthis.html). These messages can make use of [html formatting](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/richtext-html-subset.html), and can also include links to the main help.

The demo script below uses all these methods, and also shows how to handle links in "what's this" messages:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.statusBar()
        self.toolbar = self.addToolBar('toolbar')
        action = QtGui.QWhatsThis.createAction(self)
        action.setStatusTip('Enter what\'s this mode')
        self.toolbar.addAction(action)
        widget = QtGui.QGroupBox(self)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(widget)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)
        for name in 'one two three four'.split():
            checkbox = QtGui.QCheckBox('Checkbox %s' % name, self)
            checkbox.setToolTip('Tooltip for checkbox %s' % name)
            checkbox.setWhatsThis("""
                <b>What\'s this text</b>:<br><br>
                Checkbox %s<br><br>
                <a href="url-%s">link to main help</a>
                """ % (name, name))
            checkbox.installEventFilter(self)
            layout.addWidget(checkbox)

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.WhatsThisClicked:
            print(event.href())
        return QtGui.QMainWindow.eventFilter(self, source, event)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(500, 300, 250, 200)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

To use setText after a button click :

```
void myclass::on_mybutton_click()
{
    ui->mylabel->setText("My awesome text");
}
```

EDIT : This answer is in C++, but you'll be able to convert it to python easily. Just for you to have the structure.